# Beyond type theory

Tags: language-agnostic, type-theory

There has been much fuss about dynamically vs. statically typed languages.  To my eye, however, while statically typed languages enable the compiler (or interpreter) to know a bit more about your intentions, they only barely scratch the surface of what could be conveyed.  Indeed, some languages have an orthogonal mechanism for providing a bit more information in annotations.

I am aware of strongly typed languages like Agda and Coq that are very persnickety about what they allow you to do; I'm not terribly interested in those.  Rather, I'm wondering what languages or theory exist that expand the richness of what you can explain to the compiler about what it is that you intend.  For example, if you have a *mutable* vector and you turn it into a unit vector, why couldn't your compiler select a unit-vector form of vector projection instead of the more computationally expensive general form?  The type has not changed--and the work required to build all the requisite types would be off-putting even in a language with amazingly easy typing such as Haskell--and yet it seems that the compiler could be empowered to know a great deal about the situation.

Does some language already enable things like this, either outside of standard type-theory or within one of its more advanced branches?

Comment: Why are you not interested in Agda and Coq when what you're asking for is exactly what they provide (albeit with a less practical inclination, but Idris goes in a more practical direciton)? Your particular example of a clever representation for certain kinds of vectors is already provided by Haskell's vector library though. You might also be interested in LiquidHaskell and the earlier work by Dana Xu on contracts in GHC.

Comment: @copumpkin - Maybe I should be interested, but all the examples I've seen are very clunky for how useful they are, and I can't see how to extend them to a mutable and object-oriented context, which is where reasoning gets trickier and you need more help anyway.

Comment: @Rex Are you looking for a more expressive abstraction than dependent types? If so, can you offer an example? Otherwise, perhaps you're actually looking for a language that implements it in a satisfying way.

Comment: Consider asking cs-related questions in [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

there are languages with turing-complete system type. which means that your types can express any computable property. for example list of length 6 or valid credit card number. however most mainstream languages uses simpler system types. haskell is considered to have very powerful system type

Comment: Scala is one such language, but actually performing a general computation in the type system is awkward and impractical.  Thus, while theoretically true, this observation does not actually answer my question.